# Add Gesture recognizer

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have two viewController :  FirstViewController and SecondViewController

I make an animation that make a view come from right to left.

I want when a make a sweep to right the SecondViewController hide and show the FirstViewController

the animation work there is the code

```
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]      initWithNibName:@"PlayListController" bundle:nil];
// Set up view2
secondViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
secondViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x +   CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), self.view.center.y);
[self.view.superview addSubview:secondViewController.view];
// Animate the push
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate: self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(pushAnimationDidStop:finished:context:)];
secondViewController.view.center = self.view.center;
self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x - CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), self.view.center.y);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I added a buttons to hide the view with an animation but it doesn't work  ??

Comment: Why did you give us the code that works but not give us the code you are struggling with?

Comment: Your attempts to transition this way are problematic (view hierarchy is out of sync with controller hierarchy, you won't receive certain events, memory management issues, etc.). You should just use navigation controller, and if you don't want to see the nav bar, then [hide it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW9). You're doing a lot of work to replicate standard behavior that implemented much more robustly than your own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a gesture recogniser to your view.
2. In the callback, pop the view controller.

Caveat: this is non standard UI. Better go with a standard navigation bar and a back button.